# Hermitian Adjoint of Gamma matrices in FeynCalc

Tags: matrix, feyncalc

I expected the following code:

```
GA[0] . ConjugateTranspose[GA[μ]] . GA[0]
```

to return `GA[μ]`, since it's a fundamental property of gamma matrices to satisfy the Dirac equation. However, that's not what I get.

Why isn't the output of the code above `GA[μ]`?

Comment: What do you get instead?

Comment: "It's a fundamental property of gamma matrices" doesn't mean that it is implemented in FeynCalc.

Comment: @MarcoB: I get GA[0]. ConjugateTranspose[GA[μ]] GA[0] back. .

Comment: @Wen Chern: good answer! but fundamental means a basic rule, which is supposed to be implemented in a widely used program like Feynclac. If not, why? And how to implement it, please?

Comment: I don't think it is implemented in FeynCalc. You can try to do it through some replacements. For example :  exp = GA[0] . ConjugateTranspose[GA[mu]] . 
   ConjugateTranspose[GA[nu]] . GA[0];
ReplaceAll[exp // FCI, 
 Dot[DiracGamma[ExplicitLorentzIndex[0]], 
   a1 : (ConjugateTranspose[DiracGamma[_]] ..), 
   DiracGamma[ExplicitLorentzIndex[0]]] :> 
  Dot @@ First /@ {a1}]

Comment: @WenChern: It doesn't work. It should return GA[μ]